# Wp_query WooCommerce products

Tags: posts, wp-query, theme-development, query, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm currently developing an e-commerce store using Wordpress and WooCommerce. I'm planning on creating a basic product filtering system and was wondering if it's possible to wp_query the results shown by the default archive-product.php, I'm assuming archive.php works by simply querying custom post types with the category of 'product'.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use taxonomy-product_cat.php for product's categories.

and you can write your custom code with post-type='product' and tax-query.

Comment: I've got a basic idea of what you're on to, however I'm not entirely sure. Any further insight would be great!

Comment: did you work custom post types and custom taxonomies? there is no different.. '$args = array(
 'post_type' => 'product',
 'tax_query' => array(
  array(
   'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
   'field'    => 'slug',
   'terms'    => 'term slug name',
  ),
 ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );' this code lists custom term products. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters